# Filter based on row repetition of a range of values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data.frame of dates and corresponding values.

```
date <- Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:26, 26))

values <- c(sample(400:415, 10, replace = TRUE), 
            420, 421, 422, 420, 419, 421, 
            sample(430:435, 10, replace = TRUE))

df <- data.frame(date, values)
```

I want to filter the data to rows where the range 420±2 is repeated at least five times when the `date` is in ascending order. The final version of `df` would only contain rows with `values` of `420, 421, 422, 420, 419, 421`, as the `sample()` data would be removed.

I am looking for both `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  mutate(values2 = between(values, 420-2, 420 + 2)) %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(values2)) %>% 
  filter(n() > 5, all(values2)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-values2, -grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  date       values
  <date>      <dbl>
1 2022-09-04    420
2 2022-09-05    421
3 2022-09-06    422
4 2022-09-07    420
5 2022-09-08    419
6 2022-09-09    421
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rle`

```
subset(df, inverse.rle(within.list(rle(values >= (420-2) &
   values <= (420 + 2)), {values[values & lengths < 5] <- FALSE})))
     date values
11 2022-09-04    420
12 2022-09-05    421
13 2022-09-06    422
14 2022-09-07    420
15 2022-09-08    419
16 2022-09-09    421
```